# NSAsynchronousFetchRequest - should update be explicitly done on main thread

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an NSAsynchronousFetchRequest which has a completion block inside it.

I have seen various examples where some include using dispatch queue on the main thread and others don't. For example the Ray Wenderlich core data book doesn't call the result on the main thread.

Should I go back on the main thread when executing the result. Initially I thought I had to but now I don't. Some definitive clarity would be great.

```
fun exampleFetch(_ completionHandler: @escaping () -> () {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName: "Example")

    let asyncFetchRequest = NSAsynchronousFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(fetchRequest: fetchRequest) { result in 
         // DispatchQueue.main.async { // is this needed
         completion()
         //}
    }

    managedContext.performChanges {
        do {
            try self.managedContext.execute(asyncFetchRequest)
        } catch let error {
            print("error trying to fetch saving objects:", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You either let the developper to do so or not. That's up to you. You can also let the user decide on which queue he wants all the completion to happen. For instance, the `CBPeripheralManager` using delegate (not closure) let decide the dev: `init(delegate:queue:)`

Comment: @Larme just to clarify, is the result of the asyncFetchRequest called on a background thread?

Comment: I don't know, to be tested. Does it run on the a different queue, or the same one? For instance, if you launch the fetch on a background queue, is the completion called in the same one?

Comment: @Larme didn't know I could test this. Will look into it, thanks!

Comment: `if Thread.isMain`, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not explicitly call the completion handler on the main queue. Let the caller decide how to handle it. If anything, document that the completion handler will be called on an arbitrary queue. Then the client calling your `exampleFetch` method knows that it is their responsibility to be sure that process the result on whatever queue it needs.

This gives the client more control.

This also prevents a lot of needless thread switching. A client may call `exampleFetch` from a background queue and it may want to process the results in the background. If you explicitly put the completion on the main queue, the client then needs to explicitly switch back to a background queue to process the result. That's two needless queue switches and it's wasted effort on the main queue.

Comment: thanks for this. So the result of an NSAsynchronousFetchRequest is executed on a background thread and not moved back on to the main thread? In the RW book they reload a tableView within the asyncFetchRequest and don't go back on the main thread

Comment: It's not documented either way but it's unlikely that it's explicitly called on the main queue. A quick test will verify this.

Comment: Yeah that's why I'm slightly confused as its not documented and assumed it was on background but is working fine in my app when I don't go back on main thread to update UI. Did not know I could test this!! will have to look into to that - thanks

Comment: Use the debugger. Put a breakpoint in the completion handler. See what thread it's on when it stops at the breakpoint.

Comment: In theory, Instead of using an asynchronous request, could I just use a normal fetch request on a background context? i.e it wouldn't block the main thread. However, would this then just block the background context if that was then needed by another operation?

Comment: @rmaddy Can you back this up with some documentation? I could not find anything about this anywhere.