# NSFetchRequest vs NSAsynchronousFetchRequest performance

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am creating an iOS app that consists of a map. The data are stored using Core Data. When the app launches, which is the fastest way to fetch these data? NSFetchRequest or NSAsynchronousFetchRequest?

Comment: Note that the user will not interact with the app until these data are fetched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSFetchRequest` vs. `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest` is more about synchronous vs asynchronous, not really about speed. So if you're fetching in the UI context, it's about blocking the UI vs not while you wait for results to come back.

Depending on the # of records you're querying, there are other factors that could affect speed more significantly:

- `fetchBatchSize`
- `fetchLimit`/`fetchOffset`
- Faulting
- Optimizing your fetch predicate and sort descriptor

Answer (score 1):

If UI fetch makes some delay or performance problem then you should use `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest`. I think you will probably fetch some annotations so you need to use `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest`

There is a nice answer here related to your question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52973257/14531220

Comment: zeytin you mean that NSAsynchronousFetchRequest is faster? Perhaps it uses multiple threads whereas NSFetchRequest uses a single one?

Comment: Asynchronous operations allow executing long-running tasks without having to block the calling thread until the execution completes. I suggest you reading the link pls

Comment: NSAsynchronousFetchRequest protect your main thread so your user interactions will be fast.

Comment: I have read the answer in the link, but I cannot find either in it or in Apple's documentation whether NSAsynchronousFetchRequest is faster or not. I understand that it does not block the main thread, thus keeping the ability to the user to interact with the app, but does it fetch the data in less time compared  to NSFetchRequest?

Comment: think about this : you clicked the annotation to be more bigger by doing an animation. it will be happen in the main thread so far so good. what about if you use fetch request in the main thread. your animation will be wait and wait.. it is not a good experience for user. I hope i could explain.. This concept is little complicated so i suggest read about articles and test yourself by putting breakpoint

Comment: @ckc why don`t you test it ?

Comment: You are right, I wiil test it. I searched in the internet and I did not find the answer to this anywhere. If you are familiar with any articles about this, please let me know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can check out here, there are many useful link: https://github.com/seyitcodeit/200-Swift-Links-for-Core-Concepts.git

Comment: Thank you for the link. I cannot accept your answer since my question whether the NSAsynchronousFetchRequest is faster, has not been asnwered.